# What is the performance impact of changing the DB Owner in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, performance, permissions

If I have two accounts, where:

- both accounts have DBO level access (use the DBO schema to log in, and are part of the owner group)
- one of the accounts is listed as the "actual owner"
- both accounts are currently in use, and will continue to be in use, running long term (2+ hour) operations on the database
- I want to switch the "actual owner" from one account to the other

What kind of performance impact should I expect to see on the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of performance issues are you thinking of?  There shouldn't be any impact with regards to performance.  The only effects you should see would be related to security.

Comment: I imagine SQL Server will implement the security change gracefully. This means it won't drop existing connections and reset them to ones with proper permissions. Won't the existing connections, then, see a performance hit? All of a sudden the DB server is looking at two sets of permissions (old, changed) for each transaction